# Firebase database structure - denormalized data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I read a lot about nosql databases lately. I get that rule of thumb is to structure the data based on our view (of course, depends on the use case).

Now, let's say that we have a social app and the user has a profile but he also creates posts and we have to store them in the database.

So, I see some developers choose to do that like so:

```
Posts
-----UserID
-----------PostID
-----------------username: John
-----------------profileImage: https://...
-----------------posted_photo: https://...
```

This totally fits the structure base on the view. We'd go into posts and our userID and we could get all the data that our view needs. Now my question is, what happens when the user has made 100K posts and he decides to change his profile photo for example. All of his posts so far contain his old photo, so now, we have to write a method that would cycle through 100K of posts (or all of his posts in general) and update his photo. In 2 hours, he decides that "Nah, I don't like this photo, I'd change it back" and we have to make another 100K queries.

How is that (denormalized data) ok? Sure, its easier, its flat but then we have to make ridiculous amounts of queries to change a single profile photo. What's the way to handle this really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this storing user's data in a place and setting just the userID as post attribute.

```
posts:
    userID:
        postID:
            userID: 'user1',
            attachedImageURL: 'http:..',
            message: 'hey',
            reblogID: 'post4',
            type: 'audio|poll|quote'
users:
    user1:
        name: 'john',
        profileImage: 'http..'
```

It requires one more query to Firebase to retrieve user's profile data but it's a good way to solve this. It really depends on how you want to use those data.

Comment: That's exactly the way I was thinking to do this. Ok, I have a question for you though. If you have more than 1 type of a post, how would you store that? For example, you can have image post, video post, text post, poll posts, etc. All of those could also have comments, likes, reblogs.

Comment: You can just store the data in the post :) I've updated my answer

Comment: You misread that :) My main concern is related to the fact that I have 9 different types of posts (video, image, normal text, poll, quote, etc) and I dont know how to structure that so it doesnt get too nested... like Posts -> AudioPosts-> UserID -> PostID (...post info...)

Comment: You can can set an attribute `type` in the post, and then use `orderByChild('type')` to get only the type you want :) I've updated my answer

Comment: but isn't that problematic? For example, if you'd like to show only Audio posts, this would download all of the posts (despite the type) and filter them for the audio posts only?

Comment: If you use firebase's query methods this is totally fine. If you just want to show audio posts you can get them using: `ref.orderByChild('type').isEqual('audio')`. I suggest you to take a look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) link, it provides every information you need about queries ;)

Comment: if you are querying a list of posts, would you just do a batch request afterwards to get profile photos for all the userIds?

Comment: Yes. I would loop over the posts `on('child_added', ...)` and fetch the `userID`'s data. I would use a map of the IDs fetched to avoid useless duplicated requests